# Attempting to open iOS app in TestFlight causes error of "The app isn't available. Try again."

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an iOS app that I would like to distribute to beta testers via `iTunes Connect` and `TestFlight`. I archived my project, and then validated and submitted it to the `App Store`.

If I login to `iTunes Connect` and click on my app, I can clearly see my submission listed under `Prelease > Builds`. I have tried this 4 times now, and all 4 builds are currently ready and able to invite testers.

I have been inviting myself, as well as another approved internal tester. Every time we get the  `"You're invited to test.."` email, we click on the `"Open in TestFlight"` button included in the email, and then that takes you over into the `TestFlight` app.

Then the `TestFlight` app simply shows a message of `"The app isn't available. Try again."` If we tap the `"Try Again"` button multiple times, we still get the same result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the answer! Just turn off "TestFlight Beta Testing" in Prerelease -> Builds -> TestFlight Beta Testing. And then turn it on.

Comment: Works perfectly. Only thing I would recommend is to change the last sentence of your answer to "And then turn it on."

Comment: Also, for anyone who is using or thinking about using TestFlight, I would highly recommend checking out Fabric by twitter and the new Crashlytics Beta to handle your user testing. I like it a lot better then TestFlight and it does a lot more.

Comment: Could not find that Prerelease tab. Can you tell me where to find it?

Comment: In my case it was the 'missing export compliance' alert that needed to be sorted out.